# Finding the determinant of a matrix after a transformation when only given the determinant to start with?

Tags: matrices

I don't want to post the question itself because I want to solve it myself, but I need a little help getting along the right lines with it. It gives the volume of a three dimensional shape in cm^3, and asks for the new volume when the shape is transformed with the given matrix. This is part 2 of a question, part 1 asked for the determinant of said matrix. The matrix for the shape itself is not given.

Unless I'm mistaken, I can treat the volume as the determinant of the matrix that would represent the three dimensional shape, and the new volume as the determinant of the transformed shape, but I don't understand how to transform with a matrix when I haven't got the matrix for the three dimensional shape. Presumably, I need to do something with just the determinants of the two matrices, but what?

Comment: Hint: $\operatorname{Vol}(A(S))=\det(A)\cdot\operatorname{Vol}(S)$.  Where $S$ is a set and $A$ is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, the volume of the three-dimensional shape is the determinant of the matrix $S$ which represents the shape. The transformed shape is described by the matrix $AS$, hence its volume is $\det(AS)$. Now it is well-knwown the determinant is *multiplicative*:
$$\text{New volume}=\det(AS)=\det(A)\det (S) = \det(A)\times\text{Initial volume}.$$

Comment: So when it says the shape S is transformed by matrix A, that would just be SA (S multiplied by A), therefore meaning I can just multiply the volume and the determinant (For example, if the volume was 10cm^3 and the determinant of matrix A is 12, the volume of the transformed shape would be 120cm^3)?

I thought that was the case before, but I figured I was doing something wrong when it said it was transformed by a transformation having matrix A, is that just a fancier way of saying the two are multiplied?

Comment: I think so, yes. To be sure it would be better to have the exact phrasing of the problem.